# Adaptive card action not triggered

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I have dialog called "form search" which has an adaptive card. when i click submit button the control doesn't go to the next flow but ends with error . But if use hero card the button click is triggering the next flow.what might be the issue.

session.message does not contain and value and also it does not trigger to next flow.

```
bot.dialog("/FormSearch",[

    function(session,args, next) {

        var card = {
            contentType: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            content:{
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "version": "1.0",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": 2,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "Tell us about yourself",
                                        "weight": "bolder",
                                        "size": "medium"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "Your name",
                                        "wrap": true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Input.Text",
                                        "id": "myName",
                                        "placeholder": "Last, First"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "Your email",
                                        "wrap": true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Input.Text",
                                        "id": "myEmail",
                                        "placeholder": "youremail@example.com",
                                        "style": "email"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "Phone Number"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Input.Text",
                                        "id": "myTel",
                                        "placeholder": "xxx.xxx.xxxx",
                                        "style": "tel"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": 1,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Image",
                                        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Diver_Silhouette%2C_Great_Barrier_Reef.jpg",
                                        "size": "auto"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "Submit"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    // var card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
    // .title('card title')
    // .subtitle('subtitle')
    // .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, 'http://oobrien.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/googlemaps_july2016.jpg')])
    // .buttons([
    //     builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'https://www.google.com', "Navigate"),
    //     builder.CardAction.postBack(session, 'select', "select")
    // ]);



         var msg = new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(card);
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Fill in the below form'); 
        session.send(msg);


    },

    function(session,results) {
        console.log('next flow ____________');
        if (session.message && session.message.value) {
            console.log('A Card Submit Action obj was received');
           session.send('form submitted');
        }

    }


]);
```

Error message triggered

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xll9B.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/AdaptiveCards.md) regarding adaptive cards in the [botbuilder-webchat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) repo.

Specifically this:

> The `data` property of the action may be a string or it may be an object. A string is passed back to your bot as a Bot Builder SDK `imBack` activity, and an object is passed as a `postBack` activity. Activities with `imBack` appear in the chat stream as a user-entered reply. The `postBack` activities are not displayed.

As for your code please try moving this block of code into your dialog function:

```
    if (session.message && session.message.value) {
        console.log('A Card Submit Action obj was received');
       session.send('form submitted');
    }
```

There is also a good [node example here](https://github.com/nwhitmont/botframework-contoso-scuba-bot-node/blob/master/app.js) for handling submit actions.